# How much is the zoom of Sun-Pluto eclipse image

Tags: pluto

The [Sun-Pluto eclipse picture](http://www.slate.com/blogs/bad_astronomy/2015/07/24/pluto_ice_flows_and_a_ring_of_light.html) was taken from 2 million km from Pluto. At that distance, Pluto will have angular size of just 4'5". Hence this picture must be a zoomed up image. Approximately how much will be the zoom of this image? Also, is it possible to give the power of its camera in megapixel terms? Thanks for your responses.

Comment: http://spacemath.gsfc.nasa.gov/weekly/10Page37.pdf shows an example of how to calculate things like this. For reference, note that the LSST digital camera mentioned in the example has a 3.2 gigapixel resolution, and I'm guessing the camera in your question has an even higher resolution.

Comment: Voted you up for the amazing photos.   Most cameras launched in space need very high zoom to be useful.

Answer (score 4):

The ["raw" LORRI image](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/soc/Pluto-Encounter/view_obs.php?image=029932/lor_0299323899_0x630_sci_2.jpg&utc_time=2015-07-16%3Cbr%3E03:39:40%20UTC&description=OpNav%20Campaign%204,%20LORRI%201X1&target=PLUTO&range=2.0M%20km&exposure=100%20msec&imgType=approved) is 1024x1024 pixels. The field of view is about 0.29°, see section 3.6 of [this paper](http://sbn.pds.nasa.gov/holdings/nh-x-lorri-2-plutocruise-v1.0/document/morgan_spie.pdf), or abstract of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0709/0709.4278.pdf).
Pluto is a little less than 250 pixels in the raw image, corresponding to 0.29° x 250/1024 = 4'15'', well consistent with your estimate.